# Get values from beginning of file, Insert values as new columns, trim beginning lines using AWK/GAWK/SED

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

Hopefully someone can help me here. There are several thousand files that I want to combine into one, however I need to parse each file before combining. Each file is its own "site", in this case offshore wind turbines.

Each site file first contains the SITE NUMBER, RATED CAP, IEC CLASS, LATITUDE and LONGITUDE (LOSSES % can be ignored).

I would like to trim the first three lines, including the header, of each site file. However, first I would like to create a column in each file that contains the SITE NUMBER, RATED CAP, IEC CLASS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE along with DATE, TIME, SPEED80M and NETPOWER. I am an amateur with command line awk/gawk/sed and do not know how to create and fill new columns with values parsed from the beginning of the file, in this case the SITE NUMBER, RATED CAP, etc.

Input sample (beginning of each site file):

```
SITE NUMBER: 01179 RATED CAP:   20.0 IEC CLASS: 2 LOSSES (%): 16.9
SITE LATITUDE:   43.86593 LONGITUDE:  -83.50252
DATE,TIME(UTC),SPEED80M(M/S),NETPOWER(MW)
20040101,0010,10.80,13.75
20040101,0020,10.58,12.50
20040101,0030,10.83,13.32
20040101,0040,11.04,13.61
20040101,0050,11.05,13.91
20040101,0100,10.74,12.86
20040101,0110,10.53,12.74
20040101,0120,10.48,11.88
```

Desired Output (no header): where each row is  [SITE,LAT,LONG,RATED_CAP,IEC_CLASS,DATE,TIME(UTC),SPEED80M(M/S),NETPOWER(MW)]

```
01179,43.86593,-83.50252,20.0,2,20040101,0010,10.80,13.75
01179,43.86593,-83.50252,20.0,2,20040101,0020,10.58,12.50
01179,43.86593,-83.50252,20.0,2,20040101,0030,10.83,13.32
01179,43.86593,-83.50252,20.0,2,20040101,0040,11.04,13.61
```

Even though i am adding a lot of redundant data, it is necessary because i am going to combine all site files into one, and therefore need to have unique values for each row to signify what turbine it is from. Each original site file would go from 4 columns to 9 columns when parsed and new columns created.

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is what you need:

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
FNR==1 { split($0,a); next }
FNR==2 { hd = a[3] OFS $3 OFS $5 OFS a[6] OFS a[9]; next }
FNR>3  { print hd, $0 }
' file1 file2 ... fileN
```

Comment: Wow. Works perfectly! I cannot thank you enough. One thing, how do I not print the header in the output?

Comment: Actually the first row becomes. `01179,43.86593,-83.50252,20.0,2,DATE,TIME(UTC),SPEED80M(M/S),NETPOWER(MW)`

Comment: Works awesome!! Wow thank you so much! I cannot upvote your answer because I do not have enough points, but I clicked the check as answer. Thank you so much Ed.

Comment: No problem. If you're going to be doing any more text manipulation I highly recommend you get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins. Others may recommend different books or web pages or whatever but trust me they would be wrong :-).

Comment: Yea I discovered awk about two months ago and have google/stackoverflow'd my way around. I really love awk. Its amazing how a tiny amount of code can do so much.

Comment: You know if Larry Wall knew `awk` as much as Ed does, `perl` would have never been around. `:P`